# Is the Hilbert-Smith conjecture still unsolved?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, topological-groups, open-problem, locally-compact-groups

> **[Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Smith_conjecture)**   Let $G$ be a locally compact topological group. If $G$ has a continuous faithful group action on an $n$-manifold, then
>   $G$ is a Lie group.

Is this conjecture still unsolved? Is there any references to more details?

Comment: I see three references to more details in the article you yourself have linked.

Comment: These three references are a bit outdated. In february, 2011  [Open Problem Garden](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/hilbert_smith_conjecture) announced this conjecture as an open problem. I'm looking for More recent attempts to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes it's unsolved. It's known for a while that solving it (say in dimension $\le n$) reduces to proving that for every prime $p$ the group of $p$-adics $\mathbf{Z}_p$ has no continuous faithful action on any topological connected manifold of dimension $n$. I think it's also known to be enough to prove it for connected open subsets of $\mathbf{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

According to J. PARDON paper ([arXiv:1112.2324](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.2324)) it has been resolved in dimension $3$ but in dimension $\geq 4$ is open still.